# Is it insecure to pass id_token to browser code?

Tags: security, spring-security, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, cloudfoundry-uaa

I've been digging deep into OAuth2 / OpenID Connect(OIDC) and in many ways I feel smarter, but in many ways, I'm worried that a simple mistake will leave me vulnerable. I'm building super standard business apps. So time to ask for directions:

- **Platform**: Pivotal Cloud Foundry / UAA
- **Backend**: Spring Boot 1.5.x (but looking at 2.0 now)
- **Frontend**: React SPA
- **OAuth2**: Auth Code Grant with `openid` scope

I'm getting the `id_token`, `access_token`, and `refresh_token`

I have a million questions, but lets start with the basics:

1. Is it ok to take the `id_token` and just send it to the react code in the browser and have it stored in Session Storage? Otherwise how exactly is the UI suppose to know information about the person logged in?
2. If I have the `id_token`, do I still care about the `/userinfo` endpoint? My guess is no.
3. Every time the UI makes a call to the api it passes the auth code?  Does the spring code in turn make a call to the `/oauth/token` every time?  Should (or Does) the Spring Code cache the relationship between the auth code and returned tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask just for the `openid` scope, so why do you need the access and the refresh token? And since you want the ID token to be used by the React application, I would suggest you to use the Implicit flow - to get the ID token directly to your frontend.

1. You can keep the token in the SessionStorage.
2. The ID token probably contains all the info you need, so if the `/userinfo` endpoint doesn't provide anything else you want, you can ignore it.
3. Auth code can be used just once - for security reasons. So there is no point in keeping it after getting tokens. If you want to keep the backend API stateless (no session), you can use an access token. Then it's good to have a possibility to configure the backend-specific scopes at the auth server or use just the `/userinfo` endpoint to get info about the user. Or you can use an ID token if you want to treat the frontend and the backend as one OAuth2 client (the same ID token audience) and the user identity is all you need at the backend.

Comment: So this is probably where I'm getting lost.  Here is my understanding.  I want identity to be managed on the server not the client due to XSS concerns.  So I want my SPA to only go back to the originating server.  So if that is the case then my (misguided?) understanding is.  The javascript gets the id_token and the auth code.  The backend receives the auth code and swaps it out for an access_token. Then uses the access_token to call other backend services.   I wrote up a breathtaking ascii art flow diagram, but I can't post it in a comment :D

Comment: If you use the Auth code grand then JavaScript never touches the auth code - the browser gets redirected to your backend URL (`redirect_uri` param). Then, if you want to get a token or some user info to the SPA, you need to send redirect to an SPA URL such as `spa-url#id_token=base64tokenRepresentation` or to make the backend stateful so the SPA can get the user info from its backend session.

Comment: That make sense about the fragment. Never thought to use them that way.  One point of clarification, you said `JavaScript never touches the auth code` . Did you mean `JavaScript never touches the access_token`?  I see the auth code coming back to my react app, but not the access_token.

Comment: I meant the auth code. The auth code should be read from the request param by your backend and after getting tokens from the `/token` endpoint, the backend should forget the code and send a redirect to your SPA.

Comment: Lightbulb!   Even though I've been reading and reading for 2 months, you are the first person who has said "the auth code is a one time use" thing.  That is a huge piece of the puzzle I was missing. You are a Scholar and a Gentleman.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended flow for SPAs is `implicit` and in practive using the `oidc-client-js` library makes sense. In this flow the `access_token` is returned directly to the client without an additional authorization code step. No `refresh_token` is issued.

In this topology the tokens are stored client side in sessionStorage (by default but this is pluggable) and you make requests to the back-end by passing the `access_token` in the Authorization header (typically). Token renewal is not done via refresh tokens but rather automatically via silent authorize endpoint calls in the background. The downside to this approach is that if your app is compromised via XSS then your tokens are immediately available to the attacker.

However, if you're happier using a server-side flow (hybrid with form post response type) and (https-only) cookie authentication then you can. The client side code would just need to implement some kind of CSRF mitigation but would not need to be aware of OpenID Connect concerns at all.

Comment: I totally followed you until this statement `but would not need to be aware of OpenID Connect concerns at all.`. Could you elaborate? If I do the auth code + openid scope, then I get the `id_token` and `access_token`.  I just pass the id_token along with the auth_code back to the UI and i'm ready to roll? Sorry if I sound clueless here, but there are so many moving parts here. Here is what my spring code produces locally: `http://localhost:8888/authorization_code?code=dqkE277rAX&state=KH4G1M`

Comment: Using the cookie auth approach (i.e. the server-side app issuing its own cookie after validating the id_token) all the OIDC bits would be handled server side the client side wouldn't need to be aware of anything other than CSRF mitigation - the cookie is passed to the back-end automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For a SPA application the latest standard is to use the token handler pattern. Do not send any tokens to a SPA, the browser is a hostile environment for code to run in. Assume it will be compromised being a public client. Instead secure encrypted http-only (samesite) cookies are used and these are exchanged for the JWT tokens on the backend. This does mean you need a small backend for your SPA but most SPA call API's via a gateway of some sort and so adding a small Oauth Proxy is not usually a problem. To see a in depth article on the subject see...

https://assets.ctfassets.net/tldhjvq55hjd/6SrF5meJthAkypp9Q9nfPT/41ce8fde0755c3353aa6684d40e28ceb/Curity_White_paper_SPA_Security.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).